# How to filter a DataDog visualization by error status?

Tags: go, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I'm sending a data dog trace using `gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/ddtrace/tracer` like so:

```
func doSomeStuff(ctx context.Context) error {
    span, ctx := tracer.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "do_some_stuff")
    err := theActualOperation()
    span.Finish(tracer.WithError(err))
    return err
}
```

In DataDog I can see successful (when `err = nil`) and failed operations e.g. successful ones

```
{
    account_id: a_happy_caller
    duration: ...
    language: go
    process_id: 1
}
```

and failed ones

```
{
    account_id: an_unhappy_caller
    duration: ...
    error: {
        fingerprint: ...
        message: rpc error: code = Internal desc = ...
    }
    issue: {
        age: ...
        first_seen: ...
        first_seen_version: ...
        id: ...
    }
    language: go
    process_id: 1
}
```

I can successfully [search for traces](https://app.datadoghq.eu/apm/traces) **that failed** using a query like "`do_some_stuff` with an error status":

```
operation_name:do_some_stuff AND status:error
```

or alternatively "`do_some_stuff` with some value for `error.fingerprint`":

```
operation_name:do_some_stuff AND @error.fingerprint:*
```

However this doesn't seem to work [in visualizations on dashboards](https://app.datadoghq.eu/dashboard/lists) where I want to get the latency of successful runs separately from any measures on failed runs (i.e., our failed runs are maximally distorting the measure for "normal" runs). To this end I tried to place a simple "Query Number" visualization for failed runs with

```
p50:trace.do_some_stuff{status:error}
```

which doesn't work. And alternatively

```
p50:trace.do_some_stuff{@error.fingerprint:*}
```

which results in a query error.

I've tried all kinds of selectors and brooded for hours over [the advanced filtering reference](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/advanced-filtering/) but don't seem to be able to filter on either the presence (or content) of the `error` field of the trace, nor the status that I would have expected to be able to filter by, nor am I able to find an example of how to approach this measurement scenario - generally having measures on filtered traces.

How can I achieve measuring the latency using only the traces of successful or only failed runs? Or must I send different messages to achieve this?